# I would like to know the difference between GoodData project specific and user data storages, and their volatility and persistency

Tags: https, storage, webdav, gooddata

I would like to know the difference between GoodData project specific data storage and user specific data storage. I would also like to know their volatility and persistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read on Project specific and User specific data storage on our developer portal here:

Project specific:
 
https://developer.gooddata.com/article/project-specific-storage

User specific:
 
https://developer.gooddata.com/article/user-specific-storage

Note:
We preserve data 1 day on user stagging and 14 days on project stagging.

Honza